# Synchronisation object to lock in one thread and release in another

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a case where I want to acquire (lock) a resource in a function call, but am signaled of the end of the process in a callback (different thread). (The resource is external: basically, a certain bus gets busy when I start and is free again with the callback.)

With lock/critical section this is not possible at all. I also tried Mutex, but only get exceptions, probably because I release in another thread.

What are the options here?

It seems that I can

1. create bool to "manually" sync them (lock access to volatile bool, and then do a while() sleep instead of the WaitOne)
2. use events to single-thread the whole thing in a 3rd wrapper thread that then also manages the synchronization object

I would probably go for the bool though for simplicity. Or preferably any mechanism provided by the runtime.
The callback comes from an external library.

Update: I have also just now discovered the semaphore, which seems to fit my needs. I will ask anyone in case someone has a better idea/someone else finds this useful, too.

Comment: Can you be **very specific** about what you want to do? I *suspect* what you want can be done with `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` / `Monitor.PulseAll`

Comment: @Marc I want to synchronize several threads requesting my operation at the same time. My problem is that the operation takes from when I start the request to when my callback is called. From looking at Monitor in MSDN, I could not call enter and leave in 2 different threads. To use Pulse I would have to write logic that manages the access to the resource myself.

Comment: @AndreasReiff sounds like you want a semaphore, then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to solve your problem is to use an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): you wait for it in a thread, and notify to release the lock in the other thread.

Comment: @ken2k I am doing this actually to make the asynchronous call synchronous: caller requests operation and waits for callback through an event. But now I want to synchronize several thread requesting the operation at the same time, which is forbidden.

Comment: @AndreasReiff If you want to synchronize _several_ threads, then you should go for a semaphore.

Comment: Yes, I will accept for semaphore. Thanks. I somehow always missed it from the sync objects, though this (different threads) is a common case in my application.